# Unable to create CertificationRequestInfo because of some problem in ASN1Set attribute- attrs

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jscep

I am trying to create a certification request ( to eventually generateCSR) using challenge passcode which I get from a SCEP server.
But there is some issue with the attrs object and so the certification request is not getting created.

The code I wrote-

```
ASN1Encodable[] attrValues = new ASN1Encodable[1];
attrValues[0] = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_challengePassword, new DERSet(new DERPrintableString(challenge)));
ASN1Set attrs = new DERSet(attrValues);
CertificationRequestInfo requestInfo = new CertificationRequestInfo(new X500Name(subject), pkInfo, attrs);
```

The error Im getting-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in factory: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Attribute
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute.getInstance(Attribute.java:37)
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.CertificationRequestInfo.validateAttributes(CertificationRequestInfo.java:159)
        at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.CertificationRequestInfo.<init>(CertificationRequestInfo.java:81)
```

I put empty DERSet instead of attrs the CSR gets generated-
CertificationRequestInfo requestInfo = new CertificationRequestInfo(new X500Name(subject), pkInfo, new DERSet());

Can some please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using (probably due to an `import`) `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Attribute` instead of `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute`. Although implementing the same functionality (and I'm not sure why it is duplicated), these are different classes.